# Getting cakephp site to run on localhost

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite

I downloaded a cakephp site to my computer for local development. I have done the following:

-Enabled Mod Rewrite in httpd.conf
-Have htaccess files in each app directory, including RewriteBase to the directory containing app 
-Copied mySQL database and put correct info in database.php
-Restarted Apache

Currently, the site fails to find stylesheets and images, and links don't work because the server isn't translating pretty urls to resources.

Error log has a ton of errors that look like this:

```
Request URL: /css/normalize.css
Stack Trace:
#0 /home/content/73/11884573/html/tasklion/app/webroot/index.php(111): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}
2014-02-03 15:23:25 Error: [MissingControllerException] Controller class ImagesController could not be found.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'class' => 'ImagesController',
  'plugin' => NULL,
)
```

The site is on localhost/~daniel/tasklion/app/...

All the controller files are in the right places, just like the live site.

The img and css folders are in webroot. 
URL I use to access the site is :

`http://localhost/~daniel/tasklion/`

In htaccess in webroot I have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /~daniel/tasklion/app/webroot/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

What am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: Have you restarted you webserver after changing your configuration files ?

Comment: Yes, sorry it wasn't clear in original post

Comment: check error logs and update your question

Comment: lie your `/css` and `/images` under `/webroot`? What is the URL you have in browser and what is the rewrite rules you have in .htaccess in /webroot or in vhosts.conf?

Answer (score 0):

Check these two things

1. Open this file
   /etc/httpds/conf/httpd.conf
   Search for mod_rewrite.so 
   Check if 
   LoadModule rewrite_module_modules modules/mod_rewrite.so is commented. 
   Remove the comment, if it's commented.
2. In same file
   /etc/httpds/conf/httpd.conf

Search for 'Options Indexed FollowSymLinks' and change 'AllowOverride None' to 'AllowOverride All'

```
< Directory />
    Options Indexed FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
< /Directory>
```

Restart apache.

Comment: Yes I already did that, although my httpd file is in /etc/apache2, (running Mac OS 10.8.4). Still not working...

Comment: Make sure you make the change in 'Options Indexed FollowSymLinks', not in 'Options FollowSymLinks'.